# Gulp install on Windows (Npm issue)

Tags: npm, gulp

I'm trying to install Gulp for my Angular UI project and I'm a bit surprised by the fact that it won't install due to it's dependencies.  So, node installed fine, but npm.js refuses to install due to file path too long error.  My folder structure is 75 characters long, of the 260 available characters, that leaves 185 characters for npm to use.  Am I missing something here, or do the npm authors expect me to fire up a linux box for my UI? (A deal breaker)

Update:

What is the best way to install gulp as a dependency for my Angular UI project? (My goal is to ultimately have gulp become part of my TFS CI)

Comment: the path too long error was fixed in a newer version of npm, how old is your node install? Might be time to upgrade.

Comment: I think I read that somewhere, but I'm trying to install 3.5.2 from nuget.  I currently have no version installed.

Comment: .. if you're trying to install something with npm, then you have node installed.. i'm very much confused from your last comment.

Comment: Yep, I have node installed, but can't install npm

Comment: npm installs with Node, you can check the version with:
npm --v

Comment: @Steveland83 when you install through nuget, it only installs node.js, npm --v returns not found.

Comment: I wasnt aware of that - any particular reason you're installing via Nuget?
If its to allow programatic installation, have you considered something like Chocolatey? (Or Boxstarter?)

Comment: Perhaps I need to back up a bit here, my target is to get gulp installed so I can apply it to my Angular project (I'm new to Angular). I have no preference or expertise on how to get there,  I'll update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring your path length problem for now (you may want to split your question), as far as how to get gulp installed, you just need to include it in your `package.json` file as a dependency.

You can do that by running `npm install --save gulp`

**However**, that does need npm installed first.
The easiest way to do this is to download and install Node from:
https://nodejs.org/en/download/
This will install Node and npm globally, which should avoid your path length problem and in my experience is the standard approach (I've not worked with TFS, but all other CI pipelines I've worked with support Node via a container image or build option/step).

If you dont want to manually install Node, you can use something like Chocolatey to install it automatically (you can install Chocolatey from https://chocolatey.org/ and then you can run `choco install nodejs` from your command line).

Comment: Thank you, installing node separately let me install gulp to my package.json file... AFTER running npm init to create the package.json file.